# Discord.JS Checking if user has role via ID strange issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to only allow someone to do things if their permissions are correct, and currently it is just giving me this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')`

Here is my code:

```js
// @ts-check

const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

const userParam = "user"

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('checkuserskins')
        .setDescription(`Check's the selected user's custom skin inventory.`)
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName("user")
                .setDescription('The user to check')
                .setRequired(true)
        ),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');

        if (!user) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: `Could not find user ${user}`, ephemeral: true });
        }

        if (!interaction.user.roles.has("937401230316159076") || interaction.user.id !== user.id) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: `You don't have permission to do that!`, ephemeral: true });
        }

        return interaction.reply();
    },
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `user` has no guild information. You want to get the [`interaction.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=member) which has all the member's informations related to the guild.

Also, the `GuildMemberRoleManager` has no `has` method, but its `cache` property does.

So you need to use it like so:

```
interaction.member.roles.cache.has("937401230316159076")
```